# How do I connect these queries with Union All?

Tags: sql, union

I'm trying to connect these queries but I'm new to the UNION all syntax. Is it not as simple as just typing UNION ALL after each select statement? It's telling me I have syntax errors but I'm not sure how to combine these otherwise without doing Subqueries.

Below is the code I attempted to connect myself. I want it so that the below query will connect (duplicates are acceptable, thus Union)

```
    select /*COMPANY,TYPE,*/A.OrderStatus, replace(ltrim(replace(A.SalesOrder,'0',' ')),' ','0') as SalesOrder, B.MWarehouse as Whse, A.Customer, 
A.EntrySystemDate as EntryDt, B.MCustRequestDat as ReqShip, 
B.MLineShipDate   as ShipDt,  MBackOrderQty as BOQty,A.CustomerPoNumber as PO, '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
from CompanyR.dbo.SorMaster A 
left join CompanyR.dbo.SorDetail B on A.SalesOrder = B.SalesOrder  

where B.MStockCode = '" & StckCd & "'  
and B.MBackOrderQty > 0  
AND B.NCommentType    NOT IN ('O','I')   
AND B.LineType        NOT IN('4','5', '7')   
AND A.OrderStatus     IN ('0' ,'1', '2', '3', '4', 'S') Order By B.MLineShipDate 

UNION ALL

select /*company,type,*/ '','','','','','','','','', replace(ltrim(replace(A.[Job],'0',' ')),' ','0') as Job,B.Component,A.[Warehouse]  
,A.[JobStartDate],A.[JobDeliveryDate],C.QtyIssued ,C.UnitQtyReqd * A.QtyToMake as GrossQtyRqd  
,((C.UnitQtyReqd * A.QtyToMake) - C.QtyIssued) as OpenQty   
from WipMaster A  
left Join BomStructure B on B.ParentPart = A.StockCode  
left Join WipJobAllMat C on C.Job = A.Job and B.Component = C.StockCode  

where 1 = 1  
and Component = '" & StckCd & "'  
and C.AllocCompleted <> 'Y'  
and (C.QtyIssued/C.UnitQtyReqd) <= (A.QtyToMake - A.QtyManufactured)  order by A.JobDeliveryDate 


UNION ALL

select /*company, type,*/ '','','','','','','','','', A.Job ,A.StockCode ,A.Warehouse as Whse ,A.QtyToMake-QtyManufactured as OutStdQty ,A.JobStartDate as StrtDt,  
A.JobDeliveryDate as DlvryDt  
from CompanyR.dbo.WipMaster A  where  Complete <> 'Y' and StockCode = '" & StckCd & "' order by A.JobDeliveryDate 

UNION ALL

SELECT /*compamu, type,*/ '','','','','','','','','', replace(ltrim(replace(GtrReference,'0',' ')),' ','0') as Ref ,[SourceWarehouse] as SrcWhse,[TargetWarehouse] as TrgtWhse ,  
ExpectedDueDate as ExpDueDt ,(GtrQuantity - QtyReceived) as OutStdQty   
  FROM CompanyR.[dbo].[GtrDetail] 
where 1 = 1 and (GtrQuantity - QtyReceived) <> 0 and StockCode = '" & StckCd & "' and TransferComplete <> 'Y' order by ExpectedDueDate
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs on how to use UNION ALL? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union_all.asp
you need to define the same columns in each query in order to be able to union them altogether :)

Comment: Is this feasible to do with subquerying instead?

Comment: You don't need subquerying: you just need to structure the whole query to make sure that all the different parts are calling the same columns. Remember that the order is important and all of the columns should have the same datatype whenever you UNION them

Comment: SQL server really doesn't like the order By you have, even if the number of columns add up, it will always fail

Comment: So this means I need to add the same columns to each of the queries then? In the same order? @AleixCC

Comment: That's basically it, yes :)

Comment: @AleixCC would it work if I were to just add blank lines in the query to generate blank columns where there'd be no data? This way there'd be an equal number of elements?

Comment: That's a commonly used trick, yes. In case you have a missing column in one of the queries, you could do something like NULL AS COLUMN_NAME, and it would appear as a nullified field :)

Comment: @AleixCC Awesome. I do have another question. How do I go about putting my Order Bys into the UNION all statements? Do I just move all the ORder bys into one big order by at the end of the final select statement?

Answer (score 1):

to make a union imagine that you are "stacking" one result on top of the other, each result must contain the same number of columns and the same data type

```
select 'Text' textField,2 numberField,2022-04-16 dateField
union all
select 'Text2' textField,10 numberField,2022-04-22
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be `UNION ALL`?

Comment: no, it is just to facilitate reading but it can be on the same line

Comment: ohhh sorry I didn't see that it said "join" instead of "union" thanks

Comment: I have little on this site, and it seems that people are very rigid, many think they are perfect and vote negative, as if the intention was not to help, but to feel perfect, I appreciate the comment, sometimes I have to translate from Spanish to English, to validate my English and I think that there change "join" for "union"